# Issue printing different values in certain ranges

Tags: fortran

I'm running a Fortran code that should write from 1 to 2000000 on the left column and in the range 1 - 0.001 on the right column, the main code body is below:

```
program signal
implicit none

integer dt_start, dtq, dtb, dtt, mdotb, i, mdot, t_start, n, dt, t
real*8 mdotq, mdott, nmdott

mdotb = 1   !burst phase
mdotq = 0.001   !quiescent phase
dtb = 100   !time for burst phase
dtq = 1080  !time for quiescent phase
dtt = 200   !transition time
t = 0       !initial time
dt = 10     !time step
n = 2000000 !interval
t_start = 0 !start of the range

open(unit=1, file='accretion.txt', status='unknown')

do i = 1, n

 t = t + dt
 dt_start = t-t_start
 mdott = ((0.999/200)*t) + 0.505
 nmdott = ((-0.999/200)*t) + 0.505

 if (dt_start .le. dtb) then

  if (dt_start .eq. dtb) then
   t_start = i*dtb
  endif
      write(1,*) t, mdotb

 else if (dt_start .le. dtt) then

  if (dt_start .eq. dtt) then
   t_start = i*dtt
  endif
      write(1,*) t, nmdott

 else if (dt_start .le. dtq) then

  if (dt_start .eq. dtq) then
   t_start = i*dtq
  endif
      write(1,*) t, mdotq

 else if (dt_start .le. dtt) then

  if (dt_start .eq. dtt) then
   t_start = i*dtt
  endif
  write(1,*) t, mdott

 endif

enddo

close(1)

end
```

This outputs the following results:

```
      10           1
      20           1
      30           1
      40           1
      50           1
      60           1
      70           1
      80           1
      90           1
     100           1
     110           1
     120           1
     130           1
     140           1
     150           1
     160           1
     170           1
     180           1
     190           1
     200           1
     210           1
     220           1
     230           1
     240           1
     250           1
     260           1
     270           1
     280           1
     290           1
     300           1
```

and continues like that up to 2000000. I don't understand what I've done wrong with the code I think I might need to just restart at certain times or something?

Comment: Welcome, please post a [mcve] including the `end` and the `implicit none`. We need to see your variable declarations. Show us also the copy of your output.

Comment: Ah okay I wasn't sure if you wanted a shortened version of the code.

Comment: You can shorten your program, but it still must be complete and must behave the way you describe, it must show the problem.

Comment: updated the code and given the output

Comment: I don’t get it. Your output is correct for the program you wrote, but I don’t know what behavior you tried to get instead. Can you reduce it to a smaller sample?

Comment: When the code reaches 110 I want it to start writing nmdott in the right hand column. And once it reaches 310 I want it to write mdotq in the right hand column, then repeat that essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your through this perspective:

```
integer t = 0 
integer t_start = 0
integer dt = 10
integer dtb = 100
integer n = 2000000
integer mdotb = 1
! (...)

do i = 1, n
  t = t + dt
  dt_start = t-t_start           ! <- (*)
  ! (...)

  if (dt_start .le. dtb) then    ! <- condition (A)
    if (dt_start .eq. dtb) then  ! <- condition (A.1)
      t_start = I*dtb.           ! <- (**) 
    endif
    write(1,*) t, mdotb          ! <- output for branch (A)

  else if                        ! <- other conditions
  ! (...)
  end if
end do
```

For the first iterations `i = 1, 9`, you have condition `(A)` true and `(A.1)` is false, then the output for branch `(A)` is executed and the code prints `t = 10, 90` in the first column and `mdotb = 1` in the second column.

For iteration `i = 10`, you have finally `dt_start == dtb`, so condition `(A)` is true and `(A.1)` is also true. From inside the branch `(A.1)`, you get the assignment `t_start = 1000` in the line marked as `(**)`. Then, the output for branch `(A)` is executed again and the code prints `t = 100` in the first column and `mdotb = 1` in the second.

For the following iterations `i = 11, 109`, remember that `t_start == 1000` now, so in the line marked as `(*)` you will have `dt_start = -890`, `dt_start = -880`... until `dt_start = 90`, where all the time condition `(A)` holds true, `(A.1)` holds false, and you keep printing `t` and `mdotb` all the time.

By reaching iteration `i = 110`, finally `dt_start = 100` again, then both conditions `(A)` and `(A.1)` are true again, then the line `(**)` is executed again, then `t_start = 11000` now, and the output for branch `(A)` is executed again, printing `t` and `mdotb` again.

For the following iterations `i = 111, 1109`, you repeat the cycle where `dt_start` has negative/low values, still making condition `(A)` be true all the time, printing always the same output...

Then `i = 1110` makes `dt_start = 100` again, then `t_start = 111000` now, same output...

And this pattern repeats again and again, while your output for branch `(A)` is always executed, and the remaining conditions won't ever be reached.

Obviously, there the logic of your program is flawed (well, technically it is in range 0.001 ~ 1, as it is always 1... but you don't seem to like it). But I don't know what are your trying to manage to print on the second column of the output. What I know for sure is that if you want from 1 to 2000000 on the first column, you should print `I` instead of `t`.

Answer (score 0):

Or the op wants to...

"write(*,*) t, mdott"

Or

"Write(*,*) t, mdotb !But first set mdotb so it is not 1"

Or

"Write(*,*) I, t !?